# Future function call in init flutter doesn't update UI

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future

This is the init state of my class:

```
List<Webinar> webinarList = [];

  Future<void> fetchWebinars() async {
    webinarList = await context.read<UserRepository>().fetchWebinar();
    print(webinarList);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchWebinars();
  }
```

I want to display a list in which there's a list of webinars that the user has made and for that I am having a class Upcoming Events which has this init state. Using the webinar List variable (which is a list of webinar type) i can display every info that I want to. Although the webinar is getting printed out on the terminal but list view builder is not displaying anything as webinarList.length equals 0 every time. How can I improve this code to serve the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, you need to notify your view that the state changed:

```
Future<void> fetchWebinars() async {
    webinarList = await context.read<UserRepository>().fetchWebinar();
    print(webinarList);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

If you want to have different UX for your loading than just the empty screen you had if no webinars were returned, you may want to use a `FutureBuilder` for a loading animation or spinner.

You can find an example at [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this inside a `setState((){})`,

```
setState((){
  webinarList = await context.read<UserRepository>().fetchWebinar();
})
```

Because,

To see changes in the UI, you have to update the state by calling `setState((){})`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a setState() method to refresh buildcontext of states for update UI

```flutter
setState((){
  webinarList = await context.read<UserRepository>().fetchWebinar();
})
```